# I'm getting a SQL Timeout from a stored procedure on a specific OR condition - why?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, timeoutexception

I have a simple query with a few joins. The query has a about 4 or 5 WHERE conditions, but it takes up to 15 seconds to return NO results. However, if I exclude a specific OR condition, it takes only 5 seconds and returns about 20 rows.

Anyway, I thought that maybe I should refactor the OR's somehow, because they don't have any inner selects or anything fancy, just a simple condition on a column.

Any ideas? This doesn't seem to be a table lock problem, and I'm running the query directly through SQL Management Studio (2008 RC2 server).

Comment: You'll have to post the query here for us to advise

Comment: And the table definition, since the problem is likely to be related to indexes. And column types help as well.

Answer (score 2):

Possibly:

1. Your statistics are not up to date
2. Your indexes need rebuilding
3. Or you are experiencing parameter sniffing
4. You have 'missing' indexes
5. A combination of the above

More detail needed.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the actual clause itself?  String compares across large tables, for example, can be extremely processor-heavy.  If you absolutely have to have the clause in place, perhaps you should dump a "quickie" result set into a temp table and filter further using your slow clauses from there.

You should also look at your indices - the exact same effect applies; an index or two will turn your query into a two-part search, a fast index-based lookup of potential results followed by a slow-but-limited search of the subresult.

Answer (score 0):

Without any specifics, heres one thing I learnt.

```
Select * from mytable where dateadd(day,1,table_date) > getdate()
```

will run for AGES

whereas

```
select * from mytable where table_date>dateadd(day,-1,getdate())
```

is quicker. As the calculation can be done once and compared against a direct potential index.